# Automating SQL Server Dev database refresh from Prod

Tags: sql-server, database, powershell, ssis, database-replication

Seeking some advice before I dig in. Let me explain the ask and my current process.

We currently have Dev teams who require refreshed data from the Prod databases placed into there DEV databases. There requirements change, sometimes they just need tables and other times they need different subsets of the below

```
Tables
Views
Stored Procedures
Users
Schemas
```

Currently the process is completely manual and is as outlined below

1. Disable Job responsible for replication of Prod DB (actually standby)
2. Highlight Prod DB and "Generate Scripts"
3. Select the Options that is required (see above e.g. tables views etc..)
4. Backup Dev DB (just in case)
5. sp_msforeachtable and drop each table from dev db
6. Execute the script that was generated from step 2 on dev db
7. Then use the import wizard to pull the data from the prod source
8. An additional sql script is often required to run post import on new Dev DB (scrubber)
9. Enable Job on prod for repl

The SQL Server instance hosts can change as can the databases so variables will need to be passed. The SQL Servers are 2008 on Windows 2008. The box that I host the script/instance on can be any version of windows and any version of SQL Server.

I'm hoping to automate this process, at first just for the SA teams (so could be ps or cli). Eventually (hopefully sooner than later) however present this in some type of ui to the dev teams so they can manage themselves.

I'd prefer if this all runs from a management box running SQL Server and not the SQL Server instances that host the databases. I'm not sure what options are available but I suspect SSIS could be used or PowerShell and SMO and I'm sure there are other crude ways.

I'd like this to be somewhat elegant so it's easily presentable to management. I'm comfortable with PowerShell and SQL but have no experience with SSIS.

Anyway looking for some suggestions.

EDIT:

So my Requirements have actually changed. I now need to scrub the data then backup then post to a share for dev. I'm nearing completion of my script, which is powershell using SMO. I'll give a brief description below and when I'm complete I'll post more details. Prod is over wan, as are the backups. We have have log shipping enabled to my site which is the data I have to work with. Steps are probably going to make some gringe but its necessary because by db is standby.

1. Create new database by looping through source DB using smo for files/file settings
2. Backup the newly create database with standby / readonly
3. Stop Job for log shipping to source db
4. Take source db offline
5. Take newly create db offline
6. Replace newly created DB files with source db files
7. Bring both DB's back on line
8. Start Job for log shipping to source db
9. Restore new created / newly copied file DB with recovery
10. Execute .sql to scrub new DB
11. Backup new DB
12. Copy to share for dev

So thats it, all sql related work is done through SMO. I'm pretty much done, I've built out functions for each step which all work, I just have to pull it all together.

Not pretty but does the job...damn that wan!

EDIT 2:

I ended up backing up, copying local, scrubbing, backing up again with compression than copying across that WAN overnight. I did this all through task scheduler / ps / SMO.

Thanks to all that offered advise

Comment: I think you're on the right track.  You can use SMO to script the database schema and SSIS to move the data.

Comment: Thanks Mike, requirements have changed. I'm now backing up, restoring, scrubbing, backing up and then copying final backup :). I'll post what i come up with when I'm done. I am using SMO for what its worth.

Comment: If you can use backup/restore, that's definitely easier.  :-)

Comment: Out of interest, how large is your database? I'm playing with some tech that allows prod-like database clones to be created but without taking up additional storage and wondering whether this would be useful to anyone.

Comment: They'll differ, but around 100gb. Whats the tech?

Comment: We're calling it "Instant Clone" for now. It uses the volume shadow copy service. Fire me an email to David dot Atkinson at red-gate dot com and I'll point you to an early beta.

Answer (score 0):

"Automating" what you describe sounds very ambitious - probably impractical given the complexity of the requirements. I would aim for "streamlining" a process rather than total automation.

I would use the SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT) for steps 2, 3, 5 & 6. It can generate and run alter scripts for you, based on a schema compare.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/data/tools.aspx

You typically start with SSDT by "Importing" the entire database schema into a Visual Studio Project.  You can then use the "Schema Compare" tool to see what the differences are between your project and various database environments. Combined with source control (e.g. Visual Studio Online), this will give you a much better handle on what the changes are between environments, avoiding surprises.

I like the import wizard for 7 - I would save the generated SSIS packages and edit them to cover step 8 (if there is ever any reuse).  SSDT's Schema Compare tool can tell you if there are any changes, implying you should regenerate the SSIS package for that table.

Needing to ship schema changes from Prod to Dev is presumably a red flag that developers/dbas are risking Prod-first changes.  SSDT will help you monitor and quantify that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The requirements have actually changed, I am now scrubing data with .sql then backing up and providing backup to dev. I'm going to update my post. Also going to check out SSDT.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with Mike Honey, there are some big red flags here that something isn't right.

To answer the specific question, if you need to have production data from all of your tables (even a subset) I would personally backup and restore the production data on whatever your schedule is (nightly?) - you should have a backup already so restoring it should be simple.

Once it has been restored you can delete off bits you don't want and if there is any personally identifiable information anonymize it!

Once you are happy with the data you can apply the latest dacpac from the SSDT project to make sure it has all of the developer changes.

This approach has two benefits, firstly it is simpler than copying all of the tables individually and secondly it tests your deployment process pretty effectively for when you do go to production.

That being said, re the big red flags! I would really question why you need production data, the way it should generally work is that each developer has a test database with little to no data in but unit tests that verify that everything works - if you need more data for performance testing then use something like the redgate sql data generator tool to generate realistic *test* data rather than full production data.

I have seen cases where it was thought production data was required but it actually wasn't - if it is too difficult to produce realistic test data, that in itself is a sign of some bad design etc - of course every environment it unique so maybe they do need it!

ed

Comment: Thanks Ed, My requirements have changed and I am now scrubbing then backing up then providing to dev. The way I'm doing it is a bit out of ordinary but I believe will work. Going to update the post with my current direction